# TypeScript describe model

Tags: typescript

I have the described model.

```
class Teacher {
  constructor(properties) {
    this.name = properties.name;
    this.category = properties.category;
  }
}
 
class CodingTeacher extends Teacher {
  constructor(properties) {
    super(properties);
    this.programmingLanguage = properties.programmingLanguage;
  }
}
 
class MusicTeacher extends Teacher {
  constructor(properties) {
    super(properties);
    this.instrument = properties.instrument;
  }
}
```

The API returns a list of Teacher.

```
getTeachers(): Array<Teacher> {
  return [MusicTeacher, MusicTeacher, CodingTeacher]
}
```

How to correctly describe the returned data for further work?
Is this correct?

```
getMusicTeachers(): Array<MusicTeacher> {
  this.getTeachers().filter(t => t.category === 'music') as MusicTeacher[];
}
```

Or when we filter an array from different objects, how should we mark this, since, for example, Teacher does not have the field instrument
Is this correct?

```
this.getTeachers().forEach(teacher => {

  if ((teacher as MusicTeacher).instrument === 'piano') {
    return;
  }

  if ((teacher as CodingTeacher).programmingLanguage === 'JS') {
    return;
  }

  return teacher;
}
```

Not quite sure if I'm working correctly with a list of different objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are dealing with here is called a "discriminated union".  If `category` is `'music'` than the object has a property `instrument`.  And if the category is `'coding'` then the object has property `programmingLanguage`.

```
interface Teacher {
    name: string;
    category: string;
}

interface CodingTeacher extends Teacher {
    category: 'coding';
    programmingLanguage: string;
}

interface MusicTeacher extends Teacher {
    category: 'music';
    instrument: string;
}

type ApiTeacher = CodingTeacher | MusicTeacher
```

If we define a `teacher` variable as the union of two types, then typescript is able to refine the type based on checking the `category` property.  But there are some limitations.

This sort of `if` branching works just fine:

```
const teacher: ApiTeacher = {/*...*/}
if (teacher.category === "music") {
  return teacher.instrument;  // teacher is MusicTeacher
} else {
  return teacher.programmingLanguage; // teacher is CodingTeacher
}
```

But this is an error because the type refining doesn't work on our array callback.

```
getMusicTeachers(): Array<MusicTeacher> {
   return this.getTeachers().filter(t => t.category === 'music');
}
```

We can create a user-defined type guard to check whether a `Teacher` object is actually a `CodingTeacher` and another to check for `MusicTeacher`.  These will refine the types inside of a `.filter` callback due to the `is` assertion in the type guard's return.

```
const isMusicTeacher = (teacher: Teacher): teacher is MusicTeacher => {
    return teacher.category === "music";
}

const isCodingTeacher = (teacher: Teacher): teacher is CodingTeacher => {
    return teacher.category === "coding";
}
```

So now there is no error here:

```
getMusicTeachers(): Array<MusicTeacher> {
  return this.getTeachers().filter(isMusicTeacher);
}
```

In order to access a property on an object which can be a union of different types that property must be defined on every object.  So `CodingTeacher | MusicTeacher` won't allow us to access `teacher.instrument`.

One option is to check that the `teacher` is a `MusicTeacher` first.

```
if (isMusicTeacher(teacher) && teacher.instrument === 'piano') {
  return;
}
```

Another option is to tweak the definition of `ApiTeacher` such that each teacher includes the other teacher's properties as optional properties.  It becomes a lot easier to map objects in the array from the API if we say that they maybe have a `programmingLanguage` and maybe have an `instrument`.

```
type ApiTeacher = (CodingTeacher | MusicTeacher) & { 
    programmingLanguage?: string;
    instrument?: string;
}
```

Now this is fine:

```
this.getTeachers().forEach(teacher => {
  if (teacher.instrument === 'piano') {
    return;
  }
  if (teacher.programmingLanguage === 'JS') {
    return;
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w8vKVm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to avoid the type assertions that may be incorrect. More on that in a moment.

But beware that there's a difference between *interfaces* and *classes*. An interface describes an object with a given set of properties with specific types. A class defines an interface **and** an implementation. Unless your API returns objects created via those constructors (or similar), the objects you get from it won't be members of those classes, just objects matching the interface those classes describe.

If that's fine for what you're doing, use `interface` rather than `class` and yes, a type assertion to assert that a `Teacher` is actually specifically a `MusicTeacher` once you've established that's true is fine. You might consider having a reusable [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates)¹ for each interface, e.g.:

```typescript
function isMusicTeacher(t: Teacher): t is MusicTeacher {
    return "category" in t;
}
```

Then getting `MusicTeacher[]` from `Teacher[]` is:

```typescript
getMusicTeachers() { // You don't need the return type `MusicTeacher[]`, TypeScript will infer it
  return this.getTeachers().filter(isMusicTeacher);
}
```

But if you rely on the implementations those classes provide, a type assertion isn't adequate, you need to call the constructors and initialize the resulting objects with the information from the API.

---

¹ [That page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) claims it's deprecated and links to a new page, but the new page doesn't describe type predicates (yet?). The documentation is in flux as of this writing.

Comment: in the API comes the usual JSON and I create objects using the factory method. So these are returned class objects. With `getMusicTeachers()` I got it, thanks. But what to do with iterating an array, then how did I describe it correctly or not? If not, how should I do it correctly?

Comment: @cat1244 - *"But what to do with iterating an array, then how did I describe it correctly or not? If not, how should I do it correctly?"* I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking there.